# Как выбрать нужные элементы из xml c помощью xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Доброго времени суток, есть следующий XML

```
<CurrencyRateListAnswer>
<Result>
<Content>
<Item FirstCode="USD" SecondCode="RUB">69.966015</Item>
<Item FirstCode="CNY" SecondCode="KZT">50.799100</Item>
<Item FirstCode="RUB" SecondCode="KZT">4.859019</Item>
<Item FirstCode="USD" SecondCode="KZT">323.777331</Item>
<Item FirstCode="RUB" SecondCode="CNY">0.091096</Item>
<Item FirstCode="USD" SecondCode="CNY">6.070173</Item>
</Content>
</Result>
</CurrencyRateListAnswer>
```

Мне нужно забрать эти данные 323.777331

Делаю так

```
$xmlstring=file_get_contents("ссылка на xml файл");
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
        $res=$xml->xpath("//Item[@FirstCode='USD']");
        var_dump($res);
```

Но почему не работает и присылает мне

```
array(0) { }
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

1. Логи смотрели?
2. XML точно читается из файла?

Код корректный и у меня отработал. Смотрите логи и дебажте.
Апрув – http://joxi.ru/D2PBxOBH1a0qr3